# Rewrite from subdomain to file in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

this htaccess code work genially on old server, but on new is work perfectly without last RewriteRule. After put adress in web explorer for example sub.domain.com it load index.php. It may be by wrong setting of Apache? Or other?

Thanks a lot

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com
RewriteRule ^hra/([0-9]+)/?$ /game2.php?id=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /nacitanie.php [L]
```

in file 000-default.conf on new server in sites-enabled is part of enabling htaccess:

```
<Directory /home/juraj/WWW>
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
allow from all
</Directory>
```

in apache.conf on new server is part about htaccess too:

```
<Directory /home/juraj/WWW>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in condition of last RewriteRule, where in regular condition on new server must be added option with index.php

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} "^sub\.domain\.com"
RewriteRule "^(index\.php|\?)$" "/nacitanie.php" [L,QSA]
```